# It keeps showing the error, "Cloned is not a valid member of model"

Tags: lua, roblox

So, what I'm trying to create is a simple sword fighting Roblox game, while following the tutorials of a youtuber called AlvinBlox. I was doing the tutorial and everything was going pretty well, until I tested the game in an actual local server with 2 people. The players load in perfectly, but they dont teleport to the desert map I made, which is in a Maps folder, inside ServerStorage. IT keeps showing the error, "Cloned is not a valid member of model". If you want more context for the code, its inside a while loop that always runs since the condition is set to "true". When I clicked on the error it directed me to line 4, or this line, "local ClonedMap = ChosenMap:Cloned()". Im not sure what the code wants, I dont even know what it means. Please help, thank you.

```
local AvailableMaps = MapsFolder:GetChildren()

local ChosenMap = AvailableMaps[math.random(1,#AvailableMaps)]

Status.Value = ChosenMap.Name.." Chosen"

local ClonedMap = ChosenMap:Cloned()
ClonedMap.Parent = workspace

-- Teleport players to map
local SpawnPoints = ClonedMap:FindFirstChild("SpawnPoints")
```

Comment: the function is called Clone(), not Cloned()

Comment: oooooo thank youuu, i apologize for making it look like such a big deal, even though it was a very silly mistake, im very new, so thank youuuu.